# fixed bottom slidetoggle not returning to original position

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I'm creating a slide toggle (up and down) for this fixed contact form at the bottom right of my site. I was able to get it to slide up but cannot get it to toggle back to its original starting position.

Where am I going wrong?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".footer .contactformbox .sectionbar").click(function() {
    jQuery(".footer .contactformbox").slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
    }, 300).css("bottom", "0");
  });
});
```

```css
.footer .contactformbox {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  bottom: -100px;
  height: 140px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block !important;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 999999;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.footer .contactformbox .sectionbar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="contactformbox form-body">
    <div class="sectionbar">Contact Us</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lddfpsy/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to animating the `height` of an element, [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) changes the element's `display` property. This is intended to hide an element when it toggles closed and show it when it toggles open. As a result, leaving the header bar visible while its parent container is toggled may be difficult.

> If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

I suggest creating a separate element for the contents of the sliding box, as a sibling of the header bar. That way, you can hide the content box while leaving its header bar visible.

In my demonstration, below, the box consists of a "head" element and a "body" element. The body's height is set to the desired height and the element is hidden with `display:none`.

When toggled, the height of the body is animated.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".formbox-head").click(function() {
    jQuery(".formbox-body").slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

```css
.formbox {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  font-size:14px;
}
.formbox-head {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
}
.formbox-body {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formbox">
  <div class="formbox-head">Contact Us</div>
  <div class="formbox-body">Box content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lddfpsy/1/)</kbd>

```
$(".footer .contactformbox .sectionbar").click(function () {
    $(".footer .contactformbox").slideToggle({
        direction: "up"
    }, 300).css("bottom", "0");
    return false;
});
$('.footer .contactformbox').click(function(){
    $(".footer .contactformbox").slideToggle({
        direction: "up"
    }, 300).css("bottom", "-328px");

});
```

---

A down-side to the above is that clicking in the form will minimize it.  I suggest this alternate method:

<kbd>[**Revised jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lddfpsy/2/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="contactformbox form-body">
        <div class="sectionbar">Contact Us</div>
        <div class="form"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
var ff = $('.contactformbox .form');

$(".footer .contactformbox .sectionbar").click(function () {
  if( ff.hasClass("toggled") ) {
    $(ff).animate({"height": "0px"}).removeClass("toggled");
  } else {
    ff.animate({"height": "368px"}).addClass("toggled");
  }
});
```

*Note that you must click the title bar (`.sectionbar`) to close.*

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.animate()` to set , reset `css` `bottom` property of selector `".footer .contactformbox"`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var elem = jQuery(".footer .contactformbox")
  jQuery(".footer .contactformbox .sectionbar").click(function(e) {
    elem.animate({bottom: elem.css("bottom") === "-328px" ? "+=125" : "-328px"}
    , 200, "linear")
  });
});
```

```css
.footer .contactformbox {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  bottom: -328px;
  height: 368px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block !important;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 999999;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.footer .contactformbox .sectionbar {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="contactformbox form-body">
    <div class="sectionbar">Contact Us</div>
    abc 123
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0Lddfpsy/3/